# Cannot stream video with swift 2 AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swift, video, stream, swift2

I've been stuck on a problem for the longest time. I'm trying to stream video from my server. In Swift 1 I used MPMovieViewController but it's been depreciated for swift 2/iOS9. I keep reading messages about using AVKit and AVFoundation, but I constantly get an error with AVPlayer. It is:

Incorrect argument label in call (have 'URL:', expected 'coder:')

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://...")

    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url) //error appears here with the 'URL'
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    player.play()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I do it the import AVkit method. Go to your target file and go to general. Add AVKit.framework, I make sure it is embedded as well as linked frameworks and libraries. Then I go make a new file and make it of subclass AVPlayerViewController. Then I make sure that AVKit is imported in that class. Next I do the following code and just transition to that view and see the video play each time. Call the function and that should work.

```
    func playVideo() {

        let myBaseUrl = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

        guard let url = NSURL(string: myBaseUrl) else {
            print("movie trailer not found")
            return
        }
      player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

      player?.play()

    }
```

Comment: Hi mn1, thanks for the comment. I followed your instructions, but I'm still receiving the same error at your player = AVPlayer(URL: url) line. This thing is driving me nuts. I can't understand why I'm getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the optional `url`, e.g. with a ! (bang):

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
```

Comment: Hi Rhythmic Fistman, thanks for the reply. I've tried adding the ! to the url!, but I have the same error message.

Comment: maybe show more of the surrounding code. the error message doesn't make any sense

Comment: Hello, I think you were right. I created a new project and used the code that mn1 provided and it worked. After switching to the project in question, I found that it too worked... Not sure why. Possibly a bug? Anyways thank you guys a lot for helping me with this.